# how to animate page background when text is input to a field

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying create this effect on a website I am creating:
http://www.fischerspooner.com/

Does anyone know how to achieve this animation?

Thanks
Stephanie

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Hi Stephanie, its common to misunderstand how to use SO. We look at something you've tackled yourself and then see where it can be fixed or improved. It's important that we see what you've already *tried yourself*.

Comment: I'm looking for the specific CSS and javascript that would need to be implemented in order to achieve this animation when a user is typing. I am also using squarespace to inject code

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the source of the website. This is how it's done.

```
$(function () {
  $('input').focus().keyup(function () {
    $('body').addClass('strobo');
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      $('body').removeClass('strobo');
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.strob {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't she also need the style for `strobo`?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('input').focus().keyup(function () {
    $('body').addClass('strobo');
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      $('body').removeClass('strobo');
    }, 200);
  });
});
</script>

<style>
.strob {
  background-color: blue;
}
  </style>

Comment: i added that to the inject code section on squarespace, its not working, am I missing something?

Comment: I found this is the css: .strobo{animation:bgstrobe .2s steps(1,end) infinite}.strobo .mailing__handwriting,.strobo .mailing__subscribe,.strobo .main-logo{animation:strobe .2s steps(1,end) infinite}.strobo .mailing__textfield{animation:bgstrobe .2s steps(1,end) infinite}.strobo .mailing__textfield input{animation:inputstrobetext .2s steps(1,end) infinite}@keyframes strobe{50%{-webkit-filter:invert(100%);filter:invert(100%)}}@keyframes bgstrobe{50%{background:#0018de}}@keyframes inputstrobetext{50%{color:#fff}}

Comment: should i use that?